# How to filter devices which has a specific height requirement in Play Store?

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

My application needs more than a specific height in dp.
Because of that I want to exclude small-ldpi devices and support all others.

That is why I've used the following in my manifest file. Do I forget/miss anything here? Do I really cover all other devices?

```
<compatible-screens >

     <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
     <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
     <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

     <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
     <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
     <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
     <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />


     <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
     <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
     <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
     <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
     <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />

     <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
     <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
     <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
     <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
     <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="480" />

     <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />

</compatible-screens>
```

Comment: instead of `<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
     <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
     <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
     <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />` why don't you put something like ` <screen android:screenSize="normal"/>`

Comment: So,  `<screen android:screenSize="normal"/> <screen android:screenSize="large"/> <screen android:screenSize="xlarge"/><screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" /><screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" /> <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />` is enough to cover everything except small-ldpi?

Comment: no, sorry, I forgot that for compatibility you need both of the attributes `screenSize` and `screenDensity`. What you can remove from that list are those elements with fixed screen densities. All the possible densities belong to one of the values `ldpi`, `mdpi`, `hdpi` or `hxdpi`

Answer (score 0):

What you can remove from that list are those elements with fixed screen densities. All the possible densities belong to one of the values ldpi, mdpi, hdpi or xhdpi